# Entropy of a North South Transformation.

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, metric-spaces, dynamical-systems

Let $f:\mathbb{S}^2\to\mathbb{S}^2$  be a continuous north south Transformation, in other words, the point $(0,0,1)$ is a global attractor for $f$  and $(0,0,-1)$  is a global attractor for $f^{-1}$.

How  to calculate  the entropy of $f$?

I do not want to use the theorem:

$$h_{top}(f)=h_{top}(f|NW).$$

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way for this proof is see that any 2 power of the nort-south maps are conjugated, so fo every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we have,

$$h_{top}(T)=h_{top}(T^n)=n\cdot h_{top}(T)  $$

then we have $h_{top}(T)=0.$

Comment: Is it known that they are really conjugate?

Answer (score 2):

One easy way to do this is to use the [variational principle](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Topological_entropy#Relation_with_Kolmogorov-Sinai_entropy) to say that the topological entropy of $f$ is the supremum over all $f$-invariant probability measures $\mu$ of the metric entropy $h_\mu(f)$, that is $$h_{top}(f) = \sup_\mu h_\mu(f).$$ The problem then becomes a matter of understanding $f$-invariant probability measures. Suppose $\mu$ is an $f$-invariant probability measure. Then the [Poincaré recurrence theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_recurrence_theorem) implies that almost every point in the support of $\mu$ is recurrent for $f$. Since the only points in $\mathbb{S}^2$ which are recurrent for $f$ are the north and south pole, any such $\mu$ must be supported on these two points, i.e., $\mu = a\delta_{N} + b\delta_S$, where $a,b\geq 0$, $a + b = 1$, and $\delta_N$ and $\delta_S$ denote the Dirac probability measures at the north and south poles, respectively. It is easy to check that $h_\mu(f) = 0$ for any such $\mu$. Thus $h_{top}(f) = 0$.

Comment: It's an interesting solution, but at the moment variational principle is a result that I do not like to use.